# Sails.js: Route Experiencing 'Too Many Requests' Error In Chrome

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

So I'm working with the new node MVC framework Sails.js (https://github.com/balderdashy/sails) and I'm getting a weird error I've never had before. I'm trying to implement the example passport.js authentication strategy (https://gist.github.com/theangryangel/5060446) Sails.js includes in the documentation, but when I try to access my homepage (`http://localhost:1337/`) while not logged in I get routed to `http://localhost:1337/login` but it doesn't load and chrome gives me this error:

```
This webpage has a redirect loop
The webpage at http://localhost:1337/login has resulted in too many redirects. Clearing your cookies for this site or allowing third-party cookies may fix the problem. If not, it is possibly a server configuration issue and not a problem with your computer.
Here are some suggestions:
Reload this webpage later.
Learn more about this problem.
Error 310 (net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS): There were too many redirects.
```

Does anyone know what's going on?

Comment: I don't know Sails *at all*, but if the `authenticated` policy would be applied to `/login` as well, you might get a redirect loop.

Comment: experiencing similar thing in sails 1 version, what was the resolution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

looks like that message is coming from Passport.  Hop in the IRC (#sailsjs) if you want and we can take a look.  In the mean time, @robertklep's suggestion seems like a strong possibility to me.